# phonegap config.xml settings not working

Tags: cordova

I have a phonegap ios app that I used to build with phonegaps remote services.
https://build.phonegap.com/

I have a few settings in config.xml that works just perfekt there. For example:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
<preference name="target-device" value="tablet" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Now I want to build is locally on my Mac but can't get the settings to work.

I have phonegap 3.3.0 and run the following:
phonegap build ios
phonegap install ios

The app now opens in an iPhone emulator in portrait mode. Can't figure out why my settings isn't working.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What version of PhoneGap Build were you building for and what version of PhoneGap do you have on your Mac? Are you sure that the preference definitions haven't changed with the PhoneGap Version? I only ask because this is a common mistake (that I've made too)

Comment: With phonegap build I build for 3.3.0 and that's what I have installed on my mac also.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

Orientation seems to be the same. When I open the xcode project this isn't set to landscape for example. I have to set it again in xcode. Also icons specified in config.xml has to be set again in xcode. Really annoying...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about PhoneGap on Mac, only PhoneGap Build. If I were you I'd probably re-do everything on your Mac anyway so you don't get any bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This fix should ideally be in 3.4 release as per this : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5634

But people have reported problems with this after the issue was marked as resolved. So try out the latest patch release of 3.4 and see if it works.

The code to handle this preference simply did not exist prior to 3.4 althouth the docs generously mentioned about it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with Cordova version 3.5.0-0.2.1 on iOS using XCode 5. Not sure how this happened - but when I looked in my -info.plist file there were two entries for "Supported interface orientations". One was limited to landscape only (what I wanted) and the other contained both landscape and portrait. Deleting the portrait entries made this work.

I had already updated config.xml and verified from the app's package that the correct info was included in the compiled app.

Answer (score -1):

Do not place the **Config.xml** in your root folder but in the same folder as your **.html** files!

**Wrong:**
root/page/index.html
 root/config.xml

**Correct:**
root/index.html
 root/config.xml

If this doesn't work try placing all **.html** files and **config.xml** in root folder
This worked for me, good luck.

Comment: When I run phonegap create myProject, it places config.xml in the root. Moved it to www like you suggest, which didn't fix the fact the settings are being ignored.